# Axios do not set cookies on my request to my api

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a client side made with react and my api made with laravel. The problem is when my api run in localhost everything works fine, cookies are set correctly. But when I deploy my api on my vps cookies are not set by axios.

Here is my config.

I don't think this come from CORS because I can send data on my API the only problem is cookies.

```
export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://34.X.X.111/api',
    responseType: 'json',
    withCredentials: true,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a problem not having Access-Control-Allow-Origin value set to the domain you want to make the request from.

Try adding this: `Acceess-Control-Allow-Origin: http:{yourDomainName}`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i tried this and also with * but nothing change.